# How to loop through 2-d array to display data on page?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, multidimensional-array, vuejs3, v-for

This API is returning a 2-d array like this
[image]

I want to use these values to iterate and display on my page like this

[image]

I've looked through `vue` documentation but list rendering doesn't work. Is there any way I can do this with `v-for` or any other method?

Comment: can you show your `code` and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

One is to convert array to the object array and iterate as v-for and value.date and value.price in v-for=" value in array"

```
[{
 date: 'dd//mm/yy',
 price: 3242,
}]
```

Other is to use array like this, written in a way elements in array should ] be constant, where value[0] is your price ad value[1] is your date.

```
  <div v-for="value in array">
    {{value[0]}}     {{value[1]}}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, try like following snippet :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data(){
    return {
      sections: [
        [699962583, 'Sep 17'],
        [12665354, 'Sep 17'],
        [739845240, 'Sep 17']
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    currentPrize(){
      // put logic to get current prize
      return 6543210
    }
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
}
li, .heading {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
h1, h3, h5 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <ul>
    <h1>Past Prizes</h1>
    <div class="heading">
      <h5>Current prizes</h5><h3>$ {{ currentPrize }}</h3>
    </div>
    <li v-for="(section, index) in sections" :key="index">
      <h5>{{ section[1] }}</h5><span>$ {{ section[0] }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply by looping over and destructing the sub-array in the `v-for` directive. Refer to the sample below:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      sections: [
        [699962583, 'Sep 17'],
        [12665354, 'Sep 17'],
        [739845240, 'Sep 17']
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    currentPrize() {
      return this.sections.reduce(function(prev, current){ return prev += current[0]; }, 0);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 400px;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Past Prizes</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><span>Current prizes</span><span>${{ currentPrize }}</span></li>
    <li v-for="([prize, date], index) in sections" :key="index">
      <span>{{ date }}</span> <span>${{ prize }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```